# Is there an easy way to create a confirmation dialog using dojo-toolkit or spring-js?

Tags: javascript, spring, dojo

In my spring webapplicaiton I would like the user to confirm the deletion of an item before actually do it. I've looked for a simple example using dojo, but so far I didn't come up with a solution that suits such a simple and common use case.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has a built-in confirmation dialog that cannot get any simpler. It takes one argument, the message to display and returns true or false, matching the user's choice

```
if( confirm("Do you really want to delete this?" ) {
    // delete it!
}
else {
    // don't delete it
}
```

Comment: Oops. Should have researched this. The only dialog in js I knew so far was good old alert. ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

confirm is definitely the simplest way to do it, but it uses native controls.  If you want to control the look and feel, you can use dijit.Dialog.  One example can be found [here](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/8805), and it seems likely there will be some addition to the toolkit soon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Dnal Boyle gets the cookies ;-) He was faster.